# How do I export an object (that consist of many parts), so its different UVed meshes are preserved?

Tags: objects, export

I only know how to do a few things in Blender and I am stumped. I am trying to use Blender to convert fbx files so I can use them in another 3D program that has trouble importing fbx files. No matter what I try in Blender, e.g. clicking on the eyes to make everything but one item hidden and then try to export that item, etc. - it still saves the whole thing as 1 piece with no selectable meshes/UV’s that I can texturize in another program.

Currently I have to repeatedly reimport the FBX file, delete all the pieces except 1 and save it as an OBJ. Afterward, I have to reassemble all of the obj’s in my other program. This is doable, but a pain. There must be an easier way.

So in short, my question is this: How do I export the object, such as an apartment (that consist of many parts), so its different UVed meshes are preserved so I can texture them in another program? Please remember I am a nubby so be specific on how to do it. - thanks

Comment: By "another program", do you mean Substance Painter? Or what program are you texturing in?

Answer (score 1):

There is a "Selected Object" Toggle in the FBX-Export Window and also in the OBJ Exporter Window, for only exporting the selected object.

Its possible that the other part of the problem is with the other programm, what other software are you using?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying. BTW: I am exporting from Blender as an object since DAZ Studio (that I am importing into) keeps exploding the FBX files  (like a tech manual's exploded view of a item).

Comment: BTW: I just tried your suggestion and: It works! I can now export one item at a time! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

3 years late but:

Another reliable option is to show all parts you want to export onscreen (unhide), which you probably already have done

Use (Object Mode-> Select-> All) in the work window, which will select everything in view. Then export selection only

I wasted time trying to select each, then realized this clean workaround

I do wish there was a feature for "export all shown"